# How to search Games with "Google Play Game Services integration" in play store?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-games

Google recently introduced "[Google Play Game Services integration](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html)" in play store games.
How can I list games that supports "Google Play Game Services integration" using play store App or using play store site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search of the Play Store for the phrase "[Game Services](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%22Game%20Services%22&c=apps)" finds about 20 games at the moment.